# JQuery Selector Selecting Selectively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<i class="up_icon" id="1" />
<p class="position">1</p>
<i class="down_icon" id="1" />
```

I can select `.up_icon#1` but not `.down_icon#1`

```
var u = $(".up_icon#1");     //=  [<i class=​"up_icon" id=​"1">​</i>​]

var d = $(".down_icon#1");   //=  []
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should not duplicate ID like that. ID should be unique across document.

Comment: Immagine there's 2 vladiim one a bit far from the other, if I say: "Vladiim!!!?" ... which one will look at me?

Comment: and remember after switching `ID` for `CLASS` that only IE (and perhaps modern browsers) support numerical `class names`

Comment: I would have titled this question "jQuery Selector Selecting Selectively" :P

Comment: @roXon I suggest Vega's solution instead of switching as vladim probably wants to repeat the code.

Comment: @JohnVinyard suggestion noted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not duplicate ID like that. ID should be unique across document.

In your case you can use jQuery attribute selector function. See below,

```
<i class="up_icon" data-id="1"/>
<p class="position">1</p>
<i class="down_icon" data-id="1"/>
```

And then you can access them by `.up_icon[data-id=1]` and `.down_icon[data-id=1]`

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER assign the same ID to several tags

Also:

From the HTML specification:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 1):

`can select .up_icon#1 but not .down_icon#1`

This is due to the fact that duplicate Ids are invalid HTML and throw off the selector.

jQuery requires you to have unique IDs across your page or you will experience unexpected behaviours.

Taken from jQuery id selector [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

Change your HTML to:

```
<i class="up_icon" id="1" />
<p class="position">1</p>
<i class="down_icon" id="2" />
```

Now you can select `.up_icon#1` or `.down_icon#2`.

Obviously if you can find a way to apply more descriptive identifiers, other than plain numbers, to keep anything from repeating the better.
You could also use optional data-attributes `data-value="1"` to store any sequence or record id if needed. jQuery selectors have no issues with same values in data-attributes or classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch you class and id definitions. Try this instead:

```
<i id="up_icon" class="1" />
<p class="position">1</p>
<i id="down_icon" class="1" />

var u = $("#up_icon.1");

var d = $("#down_icon.1");
```

Comment: He will probably want to have several tags of each, so this strategy wont help him. I vote for the data-id strategy instead.